# java get file paths

Tags: java, file, jsp, path

I have a jsp page which contains the code which prints all files in a given directory and their file paths. The code is

```
if (dir.isDirectory())
        {
            File[] dirs = dir.listFiles();
            for (File f : dirs)
            {
                if (f.isDirectory() && !f.isHidden())
                {
                    File files[] = f.listFiles();
                    for (File d : files)
                    {
                        if (d.isFile() && !d.isHidden())
                        {
                            System.out.println(d.getName()+ 
                            d.getParent() + (d.length()/1024));
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (f.isFile() && !f.isHidden())
                {
                    System.out.println(f.getName()+ 
                    f.getParent() + (f.length()/1024));
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that it prints the complete file path, which when accessed from tomcat is invalid. For example, the code spits out the following path:

```
/usr/local/tomcat/sites/web_tech/images/scores/blah.jpg
```

and I want it to only print the path up to /images ie

```
/images/scores/blah.jpg
```

I know I could just mess around with an actual string, ie splitting it or string matching, but is there an easier way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to substring the root path away.

```
File root = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/"));
for (File file : root.listFiles()) {
    // ...
    String path = file.getAbsolutePath().substring(root.getAbsolutePath().length());
```

By the way, those `System.out.println()` lines actually won't print to the response. They prints to the stdout which may be the IDE console or the server's logfile. Further, this kind of logic doesn't belong in a JSP file. Do it in a real Java class and forward to JSP for display.

Answer (score 3):

Relying on the filesystem like that for a webapp (i.e., using absolute paths) is not good practice will make your code less portable.

You should keep your files in a `resources` directory and use the `ClassLoader` to load your files relative to the classpath. See [`ClassLoader.getResource()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) and [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). Another option is to use [ServletContext.getResource()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or [ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). You can get the `ServletContext` in servlets by using the inherited [`getServletContext()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getServletContext%28%29) method.

Comment: I don't think portability is per se a problem here since the desired files are already in the webcontent and he just want to display only them.

Answer (score 0):

Since `/usr/local/tomcat/sites/web_tech/images/scores` is the directory being listed, having `/usr/local/tomcat/sites/web_tech` as root for the output seems a bit... arbitrary.

The best thing I can think of is to have a `File root = <your intended root>;` and then do something similar to

```
String path = f.getName();
while (!f.equals(root)) {
    f = f.getParent();
    path = f + "/" + path;
}
```